# Manipulating variables between functions

Tags: c++

I've been teaching myself C++ for the past few hours (I have previous coding experience, but only very basic). I'm wondering, how would I allow the user to change the value of a variable between different functions?

**Edit:** I do have an intermediate knowledge of Python from school, but it has completely left my mind. I'm basically asking for refreshers, not tutorials. Once I'm reminded, I'll be all set. Sorry for the confusion.

```cpp
int shop() {
    int selection;
    cout << "This is the shop!" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to browse?: " << endl;
    cin >> selection;
    switch (selection) {
        case1: {
            int selection;
            cout << "Farmer Market!\n1) Seeds (T1)\n2) Seeds (T2)\n3) Seeds (T3)\n4) Tools (T1)\n5) Tools (T2)\n6) Tools (T3)" << endl;
            cout << "What would you like to buy?: ";
            switch (selection) {
                case 1: {
                    items = 1; ///THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int inventory() {
    int items;
    int tools;
    return items, tools;
```

How would I allow the user to buy some seeds in the function `shop()`, then assign a value of `1` to the `items` variable in the function `inventory()`, without needing to assign a global variable? I need `items` to retain its value throughout the rest of the game.

Comment: Does your C++ book cover function arguments?

Comment: You might want to read [a good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: At a few hours in with only basic coding experience, you probably shouldn't even be messing with functions other than `main`. Take it slow, learn some control flow, then you can tackle procedural programming.

Comment: What book would you reccomend, i dont have one but im after something that covers all the basics --> intermediate/advanced without being too dumbed down as i can pick things up very quickly

Comment: See the link in Quimby's comment for a curated list of books that are widely accepted as good.

Comment: @Liamvvvv *A tour of C++* might be suitable for you then, you can always search the internet for specific stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING: this most likely is above your level.  Change and use code with caution.**

You could use a `class` for this.  For example,

```cpp
class ShopInventory{
  public:
    int items;
    int tools;
    ShopInventory(){
      items=0;
      tools=0;
    }
    ~ShopInventory(){}
}inventory;

int shop(){
  int selection;
  cout << "What would you like to buy?\n\t(1) seeds\n\t(2) hammer";
  cin >> selection;
  switch(selection){
    case 1:
      inventory.items++;
      cout << "You have bought seeds";
    case 2:
      inventory.tools++;
      cout << "You have bought a hammer";
  }
}
```

The `class` stores your amount of `items` and `tools`.  You can create one by calling the constructor `ShopInventory()`, or by adding it to the end of the class definition (`}inventory,inventory2;`).  If you want it to be not in global scope, you can move the `class` definition into the `shop()` function.

You can get the amount of items by `inventory.items` and tools by `inventory.tools`.  You can edit them as if they were normal variables too:

```cpp
inventory.items += 10; // bought 10 items
inventory.tools += 3; // bought 3 tools
```

You can also extend this by adding more into the `class`.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the variable `item` by reference.

```
int shop(int& itemsRef) {
   //Do calculations like itemsRef = 1
}

int inventory() {
   int items;
   shop(items);
}
```

Passing something by reference just means, that the program will not copy the value of `items` into a new variable that the function then uses. ItemsRef wird ein Verweis auf die Variable items in inventory. `itemsRef` becomes a reference to the variable `items` in `inventory`. The variable `itmesRef` is then treated exactly like `items`. The advantage of this is that you don't have to return a return value, so you don't have to return `itemsRef`. Here is some more information: [learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)
This site is also a great resource for learning c++.

Comment: @Liamvvvv Happy that i could help, but if you really use the variable `items` and `tools` over and over again, a `class` might be better. If you want to make a game in your example by having an inventory and a shop, classes would be smarter.